# Excel, VBA, I need to sent rng to lastcolumn. Currently MsgBox will display it

Tags: excel, vba, explode, csv

basically i am using the TextToColumns function to separate out data separated by a semi colon in the same cell. problem is there are 2 columns of data that needs this function done and i have to insert the data without overwriting.

(go easy, first time with VBA and excel) this is what i currently have:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With sh

        Set rng = .[Q1]
        Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

        num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("P"))

        rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, num).EntireColumn.Insert

        rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With

    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With sh2
        num2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("P"))

        Dim lastColumn As Integer

        lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

        MsgBox Replace(Cells(1, lastColumn).Address(False, False), "1", "")

        MsgBox lastColumn

        Set rng = .[W1]
        Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))



        rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

ok so what i am trying to fix is setting the rng manually in the second part to W1. the rng needs to be the next empty column. so lastColumn using the MsgBox DOES return the column "W" but i cannot set that to rng (type mismatch). oh and the num variable is set to the amount of columns i need to insert. my data looks like this:

count | column with ; data need separating | column with ; data need separating

5 | 5 sets of data separated by semi colons | don't care because this is the end of sheet

is there any easier way to do this? am i even close?

Answer (score 0):

... Easiest solution if I understand your question correctly... Why don't you just make a THIRD column that equals `Column1 & ";" & Column2`, then just do text-to-columns on that single column??

Or am I missing something??

Comment: OH, right good point! this would eliminate the ability to write a header but i could live with that.

Comment: Glad it worked! - If it does, remember to mark the solution as the answer.

Comment: well it doesn't because the values for that single column is just a formula and not the actual text values. also, would i just do a macro and keep on using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your setup correctly, the following code should work.

If you process the data columns from right to left, you don't have to worry about the change in address references when the columns are inserted. That means you can use a single block of insertion/conversion code, iterated over the two data address references, which I've assumed are  `Q1` and `R1`.

Note also that I added an offset to the `TextToColumns` destination to avoid overwriting the original data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub myTextToColumns()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim rng As Range
   Dim num As Long
   Dim arr As Variant
   Dim i As Long  
   Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   arr = Array("R1", "Q1")
   num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("P"))
   With sh
       For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
           Set rng = .Range(arr(i))
           Set rng = .Range(rng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))
           rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, num).EntireColumn.Insert
           rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
              Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
              FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
       Next
   End With
End Sub
```